(Python) Получить номер строки sqlite3
Смотрите, у нас есть база данных users в которой есть значения id, cash. id - это ну айди пользователя, а cash, грубо говоря, его деньги. Нам нужно как-то получить место пользователя по деньгам среди всех. Можно было бы получить отсортированный список всех пользователей и потом пройтись по каждому,  но если будет там 100000 людей, то это долго, а так надо как будто дать запрос в sqlite по типу "SELECT (номер строки) FROM users WHERE id = {айди пользователя} ORDER BY cash DESC", может кто знает как сделать то, что мне нужно

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Получить номер строки после сортировки

Мне нужно получить номер строки для 1 пользователя

если я укажу "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cash) AS RowNumber FROM users WHERE id = {тут айди пользователя}", то будет высвечиваться единичка, так как идет сортировка по пользователям только с 1 айди, а мне надо просто получить номер строки в отсортированном где айди будет равен конкретному

Уберите фильтр WHERE из подзапроса в ROW_NUMBER

"SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cash) AS RowNumber FROM users" так если такая строка будет, то я не получу номер строки конкретного пользователя

Серьёзно?  Может надо было указать id в своём SELECT и уже к основному запросу применить фильтр?  См. ответ

@ART, Найдите отличие от ответа в вопросе-дубликате
select id, row_number() over (order by cash desc) rn
from users
where id = $your_id

DB Fiddle demo

dict(cursor.execute(f"SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cash DESC) AS RowNumber FROM users").fetchall()).get(member.id) вот мой ответ, я быстрее сам догадался, чем мне сказали

"Догадаться" было сложно, да..
